# How to use Angular validation properties inside for?

Tags: angular, validation

I am trying to find out if the input element in the iteration of a for(*ngFor) loop iteration is dirty but I cannot find a way to dynamically name the validation variable, therefore cannot get the outcome I am looking for.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
  <td>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input id="{{user.id}}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.name" #[user.id]="ngModel" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <button *ngIf="[user.id].dirty" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please give brief description what you exactly want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation properties can be found on AbstractControl instances. So you need to mark your form tag and then get a particular control from its controls property:

```
<form #myFrom="ngForm">
    <input name="myInput{{user.id}}">
    {{ myForm.controls['myInput' + user.id]?.dirty }}
</form>
```

Comment: Ok but how would I apply this to a butt9n like in my example

Comment: You can use the "myForm.controls..." (boolean) expression in the *ngIf of the button.